# Why does this Autologin command work?

Tags: command-line

I installed [minimal Ubuntu 12.10](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD).  I want this environment to take as little disk space as possible, so I didn't install a desktop and am doing everything via console.  I want to auto-login to the system when it is booted.  I discovered a method for auto-login, but I do not fully understand it.

I edited the file **/etc/init/tty1.conf** and changed the last line from

```
exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
```

to

```
exec /bin/login -f username < /dev/tty1 > /dev/tty1 2>&1
```

...where "username" is the name of the user to login.  It works perfectly, but why?  I understand "login -f username" and redirection, but I don't see where the auto-login magic is happening.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the answer is found in the man page: `man login`.

In your original command, `getty` does some setup (see the man page) prompts for a login name, and invokes `login`. In your new command, you're bypassing `getty` and invoking login directly. The key is the `-f` option. The manual says of it:

> Do not perform authentication, user is authenticated.  Note: In that case, *username* is mandatory.

Since `login` is the program that handles logins, it can easily bypass authentication if necessary.